# Quotient to make $X$ a $T_1$ space

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces, separation-axioms

Let $X$ be a topological space. We define a relation on $X$:
$$x \approx y : \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad x \in \overline{\{y\}}.$$
In general $\approx$ is no equivalence relation since it lacks symmetrie. But of course it generates an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $X$ (the smallest equivalence relation containing $\approx$).

My question: Is $X/\sim$ a $T_1$ space?

Or in other words: Are the equivalence classes of $\sim$ closed?

Comment: In general, you must iterate this construction transfinitely to get a $T_1$ space.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2372639/left-adjoints-to-some-inclusions-of-categories-of-topological-spaces for some related discussion.

Comment: @EricWofsey Thanks. That's helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the topology on $X=[0,\infty)$ generated by **closed** subsets $[a,\infty)$ and with addition of $\{0\}$ as a closed subset. So open subsets are generated by $[0,a)$ and $(0,\infty)$. You can verify that $A\subseteq [0,\infty)$ is closed if and only if $A$ is of the form $\{0\}$ or $[a,\infty)$ or $\{0\}\cup[a,\infty)$. It follows that

$$\overline{\{x\}}=\begin{cases}
[x,\infty) &\text{if }x>0 \\
\{0\} &\text{for }x=0
\end{cases}$$

As a consequence $0\not\sim x$ if $x>0$.

On the other hand you can easily check that if $x,y>0$ then $x\sim y$.

Combining these two we get that the equivalence class $[1]_\sim=(0,\infty)$ is not closed. In fact the quotient space $X/\sim$ is equal to $\{[0],[1]\}$ with topology (of open subsets) $\{\emptyset, \{[1]\}, X/\sim\}$.

Comment: Note that you can just use $[0,\infty)$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$, which maybe makes the example a bit easier to think about.

Comment: @freakish Ok, I misunderstood you. My bad. I thought you take $[x,\infty)$ as open sets

Comment: @freakish Thank you very much for your answer. I don't think that you need transfinite induction to prove $0\not\sim x$ for $x>0$. It follows directly from your characterization of $\overline{\{x\}}$.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain Eee, it seems that to obtain $\sim$ you need the [transitive closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure) of $\approx$ first (is $\approx$ transitive?) and then you apply the [symmetric closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_closure). These have to applied to show that $0\not\sim x$.

Comment: @freakish The relation $\approx$ is already transitive. When you have $x \in \overline{\{y\}}$ and $y \in \overline{\{z\}}$, then it follows $\overline{\{y\}} \subseteq \overline{\{z\}}$, so you have $x \in \overline{\{z\}}$ as well.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain Ah, yes, you're right. I'm a bit tired. In that case this is a simple symmetric closure.

Comment: @freakish In your space you just need a symmetric closure. There are other spaces though where after a symmetric closure the relation lacks transitivity. So then a transitive closure has to follow. But after that you are always done and your relation is an equivalence relation.